# Hints or pointers with this specific situation

Tags: matlab

First time programming here. So I wrote this function in matlab to find roots of cubic polynomials using iterative processes. The function has to get the number of roots right, so at the end, I used if statements to get rid of a root if it were sufficiently close to any other root I've found, because it's probably a repeated root. However, the problem with this, as I just found out, is that if the coefficients of the polynomial are super small, the roots will all be super close to 0. My code will output that there is only one root, 0, when really it should display 3 solutions of 0.

I feel like this is a rather difficult predicament because the iterative processes will never get the exact numbers twice for a double root, so it isn't a matter of just comparing if the numbers are exactly the same. It could be that they're actually two different roots, just very close to one another. Any suggestions?

Edit: This is the code I wrote to get it to not display double roots twice, but I've realized this could potentially get rid of actual roots.

```
rts = [root1, root2, root3];
if abs(root1 - root2) < 1*10^(-7)
    rts = [root1, root3];
end
if abs(root1 - root3) < 1*10^(-7) 
    rts = [root1, root2];
end

if abs(root2 - root3) < 1*10^(-7) 
    rts = [root1, root2];
end

if abs(root1 - root2) < 1*10^(-7) && abs(root1 - root3) < 1*10^(-7)
    rts = root1;
end
```

Comment: Look at the `eps`-function (http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html). If you let this "sufficiently close"-parameter depend on `eps` of the two values you want to compare, you might be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you post a minimal code example? How do you exactly do the conditional if statement? How do you detect and display the number of roots?

Comment: Hi JaBe. I added the code I used at the end of my function. To count the number of roots I just need that number of roots to show up. I need at least an accuracy of 1e-6 so that's why I chose 1e-7 to be a sufficiently close condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your roots in the `rts` array are monotolly increasing. The problem with your code is that you overwrite your `rts` array, depending on which conditions are true. Use a new variable for the unequal roots `different_rts`.

If the difference of the next root to the last stored root is greater than the treshold, add it to the array.

```
rts = [ 0 1e-8 0.1 ]  

nDifferent = 1;         % number of different roots
different_rts = rts(1)  % initialize with first value
for ri=2:numel(rts)     
    if( abs(different_rts(nDifferent)-rts(ri))>1e-7 ) % if difference is greater add next root
        nDifferent = nDifferent + 1;
        different_rts(nDifferent) = rts(ri); 
     end
end
```